# What is causing the doors to move?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, everyday-life

New to physics SE (physics too). Today I Observed a strange thing. In my house there are a pair of doors attached to same wall (the wall is about 30 cm wide), both are oppositely hinged (note: we need to **push** one door to close and other door to open). In this case when I open one door quickly, the other door closes. If I close the same door, the other door opens. what causes this? IS this due to pressure difference? or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with opposite hinges, pulling one door open raises the air pressure inside the room for just a moment, which pushes the other door shut, and the opposite is true too. If you open a window in that room you will note that this effect will either go away or be made much weaker.